# Update XML variable in SQL Server 2005 with namespace

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xsd, xquery-sql

I'm trying to add a new node to an XML variable containing namespaces using TRANSACT SQL, but there is no error, nor the variable is updated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
declare @xml xml;
set @xml = '<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="ecasData">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element id="cmbZona" name="cmbZona" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation>#ZONA#</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
                    </xs:simpleType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>';
set @xml.modify('insert <xs:test>1</xs:test> 
into (/xs:schema/xs:element[@name="ecasData"])[0]');
select @xml;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
into (/xs:schema/xs:element[@name="ecasData"])[1]');
```

did the magic.